# Entra Id (AAD) certificate based authentication (CBA) client certificate validation failed ("invalid request") error

Tags: authentication, entra-id, self-signed-certificate, x509

I'm trying to get CBA to work according to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/how-to-certificate-based-authentication

I created a self-signed CA for testing purposes and issued a client certificate signed by the CA. The CA is uploaded to Entra Id, CBA is turned on and the user to whom the certificate is issued is in the enabled test group. Certificate and the CA are installed on the client machine cert store.

When I navigate to https://myapps.microsoft.com and enter the user email, I have an option to use a certificate to sign in.  However, when I click that option (no cert select box because I only have that one cert), I get the error message certificate validation failed.

Checking the sign-in logs for the user I can see the attempted certificate based sign-in marked as failed with error code 50192. All resources I can find simply say this means "Invalid request." (duh)

I can't figure out what's wrong. The certificate has both the common name and email address fields set to the UPN, and X509v3 subject alternative name is set to

```
otherName:1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:<the UPN>
```

Certificate extended key usage is "TLS Web Client Authentication, Microsoft Smartcard Login, EAP over PPP, EAP over Lan" and X509v3 key usage is "Key Encipherment".

In Entra Id under auth binding, I have the certificate issuer binding active (and the self-signed CA selected which is the only CA I have). I tried turning that off but that didn't change anything).

In username binding cert fields PrincipalName and RFC822Name have binding set to userPrincipalName, and Subject to CertificateUserIds. I tried turning those selectively off to no avail.

I also tried adding X509:(the UPN) and X509:(the UPN) to the user authorization info properties, still no luck.

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's because of the self signed cert, do you have a crl published for that signed certificate according to the requirements `Each CA should have a certificate revocation list (CRL) that can be referenced from internet-facing URLs. If the trusted CA doesn't have a CRL configured, Microsoft Entra ID won't perform any CRL checking, revocation of user certificates won't work, and authentication won't be blocked.`

Comment: Check your certs with the requirements